# ReferenceError when adding for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, dom

I get a weird `ReferenceError: fetchRemoteClusters is not defined` when I add a for loop inside my `fetchRemoteClusters` function.
When I remove the for-loop and simply do an alert or anything else it works just fine.

My function looks like this

```
function fetchRemoteClusters(location)
{
var select = document.getElementById("Pantheoncluster");
var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];

for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.text = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.add(el);
   }​
}
```

Here's where I' calling the function

```
<input type="checkbox" id = "<?php echo $this->LOC2?>" name="<?php echo $this->LOC2?>" value="<?php echo $this->LOC2?>" onclick="fetchRemoteClusters('<?php echo $this->LOC2?>')"><?php echo $this->LOC2?>
```

What could be causing this? Please help.

Comment: You're not calling it anywhere in the code you posted. Please add your full code.

Comment: @JackBashford when I remove the for-loop and simply do an `alert` or anything else it works just fine. That is why I'm quite sure it something to do with the for-loop. I'm calling the function on-click from my front-end BTW.

Comment: Post the actual code from the page, not the server code that generates it.

Comment: There's an illegal \u200b character next to the closing curly bracket in the code for the for loop. Remove that and your script will work fine. [See it at line 12](https://jsfiddle.net/pfq0ywtz/).

Comment: @Teemu I think that was the issue. I scrapped and rewrote the entire thing and worked just fine. If you could elaborate the issue and post it as an answer I Believe it will be helpful to others.

Comment: I'm not sure how this should be treated, actually it's a typo, despite of it can't be seen easily.